# Why does an empty ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable() corrupt my Xamarin.Forms ListView, but simple ICommand works?

Tags: system.reactive, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I have a very simple setup: A `ContentPage` has a `ListView` as it's only content. The list supports pull to refresh. It is binding to a command:

```
listView.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(ListView.RefreshCommandProperty, vm => vm.RefreshCommand);
listView.SetBinding<MyPageViewModel>(ListView.IsRefreshingProperty, vm => vm.IsRefreshing);
```

The list is empty and binds to an empty collection.

The refresh command is:

```
public ICommand LoadNodesCommand { get; set; }
```

If I use

```
LoadNodesCommand = new Command(o => {
  IsRefreshing = true;
  IsRefreshing = false;
});
```

the list refreshes if I pull and all is fine. Notice that I do not modify the list's data. It's an empty dummy command.

Next I use this as my command instead:

```
LoadNodesCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(x =>
{
  IsRefreshing = true;
  IsRefreshing = false;

  return System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Empty<IEnumerable<Item>>();
}
```

Again, an empty dummy command. But this one makes the ListView behave very strangely. After the pull-to-refresh, it scrolls a bit. After each refresh it scrolls further. I do not use any other Rx methods (I'm not subscribing to the observable). Here's a screenshot of the list after three refreshes. Its first cell has been moved towards the bottom of the screen.

It really *should not* affect ListView...I'm not touching it, nor its data. I also tried using `Device.BeginInvokeMainThread()` to set the `IsRereshing = false`.

[image]